# Replace array contain according to its occurrences

Tags: swift

How to replace number string with its corresponding Alphabet Characters in Array.

```
Example:
["1","2","3","3","2","3"]

Replace: 1 -> A, 2-> B, 3-> C

Result should be 
["A","B","C","C","B","C"]
```

Comment: And what result would you expect for the input array `[ "", "100000", "-3.14", "π", "" ]` ?

Comment: Like ["A","B","C","C","B","C"]. If array contains an element with String "1" then it should be converted into "A" and likewise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use `Dictionary` for replacement rules:

```
let array = ["1", "2", "3", "3", "2", "3"]

let replacementRules = ["1": "A", "2": "B", "3": "C"]

let result = array.map{replacementRules[$0] ?? $0}
print(result)
//["A", "B", "C", "C", "B", "C"]
```

Answer (score 1):

If your array contain string value till 1-26, you can try like this

```
    let alphabetArray = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"]
    let arr = ["1","2","3","3","2","3"]
    var newArr = [String]()
    newArr = arr.map { (item) in
        alphabetArray[Int(item)! - 1]
    }
    print(newArr)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = ["1","2","3","3","2","3"]
for i in 0..<arr.count {
    switch(arr[i]) {
        case "1":
            arr[i] = "A"
            break
        case "2":
            arr[i] = "B"
            break
        case "3":
            arr[i] = "C"
            break
    default: break
    }

}
```